# Function takes an array of length 8 as an argument

Tags: c, arrays, function, args

I don't understand my error message

```
triangle_test.c: In function ‘defineLines’:
triangle_test.c:89:1: error: argument ‘args’ doesn’t match prototype
triangle_test.c:25:5: error: prototype declaration
```

I don't know if I'm supposed to pass &TriHolder, 8?  I have never done arrays in C before and need a little bit of help on this one.

```
int defineLines(float TriHolder[], int args);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  initialize_TriHolder(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4);
  getInputTriVerts();
  getInputInteriorPoint();
  defineLines(&TriHolder[0],8); //this is the array I want to pass
}  

defineLines(args, length)
{
  lineAB[0]=TriHolder[0]; //Ax
  lineAB[1]=TriHolder[1]; //Ay
  lineAB[2]=TriHolder[2]; //Bx
  lineAB[3]=TriHolder[3]; //By
  slopeAB = (lineAB[3]-lineAB[1])/(lineAB[2]/lineAB[0]);
  interceptAB = slopeAB * -lineAB[0] + lineAB[1]; //b: y - y1 = m( x - x1 ), x = 0
  ///////////////////////////
  lineBC[0]=TriHolder[2];//Bx
  lineBC[1]=TriHolder[3];//By
  lineBC[2]=TriHolder[4];//Cx
  lineBC[3]=TriHolder[5];//Cy
```

Comment: This is not valid C. Define the function also with the complete prototype, that is with return type and argument types.

Comment: `&TriHolder[0]` and `TriHolder` denote exactly the same value of exactly the same type. Make sure the type of `TriHolder` is array of `float`.

Comment: your variable names are a bit confusing `defineLines(float TriHolder[], int args);` vs. `defineLines(args, length)`. What is args in the second context?

Comment: Mr。 Henderson， args and length was something I pulled off of [link](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch8x.htm) A C Pointer tutorial, when I was trying to figure this out.  I thought args was a magic word that some how denoted that an array would be passed in.

Comment: Thank you Jens, I didn't know to do that.  I thought you put that stuff up at the top before main and then forgot about it.  I'm coming from limited Python and Ruby and still not used to declaring types I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use pre-ANSI form for function parameters. The following should compile:

```
int defineLines(float TriHolder[], int args);

int main(void)
{
  /* ... */
}

int defineLines(float triHolder[], int args)
{
  /* .. */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function header:

```
defineLines(args, length){
```

needs to match your prototype:

```
int defineLines(float TriHolder[], int args);
```

Note the missing key words (float, int, etc). So something more like:

```
int defineLines(float args[], int length){
```

Is what you're looking for. You're missing the definitions of `TriHolder` and `lineAB`, but from your code presumably they are some global arrays of floats. (please confirm).

Also, you can pass an array as:

```
fineLines(TriHolder,8);}  //this is the array I want to pass
```

However if my prior assumption was correct and `TriHolder` is global, why bother passing it at all?

Comment: wow you 2 first posters were fast, ok, so I have to change the function header to say defineLines(float TriHolder[], int args){ //body of function; return EXIT_SUCCESS;}, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your prototype for `defineLines` is correct, however you need to call it this way:

```
defineLines(TriHolder,8);
```

The name `TriHolder` on its own is actually a pointer to the 0th array index, it is equivalent to `TriHolder[0]`.

Comment: you were very fast to help me, 谢谢 Jing Tao